# Sub-select takes "ages" - EXCEPT is much faster

Tags: postgresql-9.3, performance, subquery, except, postgresql-performance

## Script to create the tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS history;
CREATE TABLE history (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    ticket_id integer NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE ONLY history ADD CONSTRAINT history_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
CREATE INDEX history_ticket_id ON history USING btree (ticket_id);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ticket;
CREATE TABLE ticket (
    id integer NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE ONLY ticket ADD CONSTRAINT ticket_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

## Dummy data

```
INSERT INTO history values (generate_series(1, 30000), generate_series(1, 30000));
ANALYZE history;

INSERT INTO ticket values (generate_series(1, 40000));
ANALYZE ticket;
```

## Query with sub-select

```
explain analyze select distinct ticket_id from history
       where ticket_id not in (select id from ticket);
```

## explain analyze slow sub-select

```
     HashAggregate  (cost=15510545.50..15510695.50 rows=15000 width=4) (actual time=170892.668..170892.668 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on history  (cost=0.00..15510508.00 rows=15000 width=4) (actual time=170892.644..170892.644 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 30000
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..934.00 rows=40000 width=4) (actual time=0.006..2.685 rows=15000 loops=30000)
                 ->  Seq Scan on ticket  (cost=0.00..577.00 rows=40000 width=4) (actual time=0.038..21.347 rows=30000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 170892.965 ms
```

## Query with EXCEPT

```
explain analyze select distinct ticket_id from history
       except select id from ticket;
```

## explain analyze with EXCEPT

```
HashSetOp Except  (cost=0.29..2449.29 rows=30000 width=4) (actual time=41.641..41.641 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.29..2274.29 rows=70000 width=4) (actual time=0.024..27.835 rows=70000 loops=1)
         ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.29..1297.29 rows=30000 width=4) (actual time=0.024..14.527 rows=30000 loops=1)
               ->  Unique  (cost=0.29..997.29 rows=30000 width=4) (actual time=0.022..10.856 rows=30000 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Only Scan using history_ticket_id on history  (cost=0.29..922.29 rows=30000 width=4) (actual time=0.021..6.031 rows=30000 loops=1)
                           Heap Fetches: 30000
         ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..977.00 rows=40000 width=4) (actual time=0.018..8.364 rows=40000 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on ticket  (cost=0.00..577.00 rows=40000 width=4) (actual time=0.018..3.808 rows=40000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 41.702 ms
```

## DBMS version

- PostgreSQL 9.3.10

## Questions

- Why does one take much longer than the other?

Comment: The first plan shows `Index Scan using history_pkey on history  (...rows=1389582)` the second plan shows `Index Scan using history_pkey on history  (... rows=2738415)`. So the second plan expects nearly twice as much rows as the first one. Given that this is the primary key index, it's strange that the same `where` condition would result is such a drastic difference in the estimates. Do you have an index on `history.id`?

Comment: Thanks for the test-setup. On my 9.5.1 installation the `not in` is about twice as fast as the `except` solution: [not in execution plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/brN) and [except plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/dmik)

Answer (score 1):

`in` is better for list of constant values. Try using `not exists` instead.

Query:

```
explain analyze select distinct ticket_id from history h
       where not EXISTS (select id from ticket t where t.id = h.ticket_id);
```

And execution plan:

```
Unique  (cost=0.58..2294.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=23.140..23.140 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=0.58..2294.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=23.139..23.139 rows=0 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (h.ticket_id = t.id)
        ->  Index Only Scan using history_ticket_id on history h  (cost=0.29..922.29 rows=30000 width=4) (actual time=0.037..6.848 rows=30000 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 30000
        ->  Index Only Scan using ticket_pkey on ticket t  (cost=0.29..1228.29 rows=40000 width=4) (actual time=0.026..6.970 rows=30000 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 30000
Total runtime: 23.189 ms
```

Reason for that I think is that for `NOT IN` Postgres will need to build distinct list of values from table `ticket` and then only filter `history`.
`NOT EXISTS` does not need to create a list. It can just check if value exists in tickets PK index.

Usually when you don't get "Anti Join" in such type of queries - something is written bad.

Comment: We usually appreciate more detailed answers and justified claims. Is `IN` always slow when combined with subqueries? Why? What plans are produced? Cared to share some analysis / benchmarks? Why do you suggest `NOT EXISTS`? There are at least two other basic ways to write such queries  besides using `IN` and `NOT EXISTS`: Using `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` and `EXCEPT` (what the OP did). And you haven't answered the OP's question. Why the `EXCEPT` solution is so much faster in this case?

Comment: Thank you for providing a third way to get the result. Yes, your "NOT EXISTS" solution is fast even on the old Postgres 9.3 where the sub-select version takes ages. But it takes twice as long as the EXCEPT version. One question still remains: Why is the sub-query that slow in the old postgres version. But this question is just for curiosity. My initial goal is reached. My conclusion: Upgrade to newer DB version.

Comment: Planner is getting smarter with newer versions. I would say this is the main reason :)